# How can use SSIS to run command delete with bind variable in Vertica target

Tags: sql-server, ssis, vertica

I tried to use SSIS to transfer CDC data from SQL Server to Vertica.
but I'm stuck at the step for delete data on target.

For SQL server --> SQL Server : when the source sent date for delete or update, I will use "OLE DB Command" to run `delete from targetTB where ID=?` first then insert the row update.

but when I tried to change target to Vertica, It cannot use "OLE DB Command".

So I tried to  use the "Execute SQL Task" to select the ID from the update rows and keep result in the Full Resultset. Then use another "Execute SQL Task" for use command  `delete from targetTB where ID=?` but I'm not sure how to mapping the parameter with the resultset. it error about the variable type.

Could anyone advise me the solution that I can send sql command to the Vertica database.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid firing UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT commands with single rows .

I would rather build a staging table with the same structure, and then, for example:

```
MERGE /*+DIRECT*/
INTO d_cust_scd t
USING stg_d_cust_scd s
  ON s.cust_key=t.cust_key
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  cust_key     = s.cust_key
, cust_id      = s.cust_id
, cust_from_dt = s.cust_from_dt
, cust_to_dt   = s.cust_to_dt
, cust_is_curr = s.cust_is_curr
, cust_cre_ts  = s.cust_cre_ts
, cust_udt_ts  = s.cust_udt_ts
, cust_fname   = s.cust_fname
, cust_lname   = s.cust_lname
, cust_phoneno = s.cust_phoneno
, cust_loy_lvl = s.cust_loy_lvl
, cust_org_id  = s.cust_org_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  cust_key
, cust_id
, cust_from_dt
, cust_to_dt
, cust_is_curr
, cust_cre_ts
, cust_udt_ts
, cust_fname
, cust_lname
, cust_phoneno
, cust_loy_lvl
, cust_org_id
) VALUES (
  s.cust_key
, s.cust_id
, s.cust_from_dt
, s.cust_to_dt
, s.cust_is_curr
, s.cust_cre_ts
, s.cust_udt_ts
, s.cust_fname
, s.cust_lname
, s.cust_phoneno
, s.cust_loy_lvl
, s.cust_org_id
);
```

Comment: May you explain, please, why ? "I would avoid firing UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT commands with single rows"

Comment: Vertica is a database purpose built for dealing with mass data. Queries that touch millions or billions of rows. So OLAP workloads rather than OLTP workloads. If you want to grind a Vertica database to a halt, run tens of thousands of single-row updates/inserts in seconds, and commit each of them. Vertica is good where other DBMSs fail: run transactions of billions of rows involved. Even if they fail, they rollback much more gently than in other DBMSs.